# Page Pagination in PHP

Tags: php, pagination

Please, I'm new to PHP. and I've built a webapp with numerous links to page contents that span more than 5 pages. The database works fine, but once I populate the pages, they cannot appear on a single page so i tried the Page Pagination.
Now here's the catch: my code throws me to just a single page as opposed to, say, 10 page links to a page. I've checked the available solutions on the net and mine seems quite peculiar so it's difficult to get the code to work.

Here is a snippet:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1))) {

    // Get the category title:
    $sql = 'SELECT category FROM categories WHERE id = ' . $_GET['id'];
    $result = $dbc->query($sql); // Use prepared statement instead
    if ($result->num_rows != 1) { // Problem!
        $page_title = 'Error!';

    $page_no = $_GET['id'];
    $no_of_records_per_page = 2;
    $offset = ($page_no - 1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
    // Get the number of total pages
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages';
    $result = $dbc->query($sql);
    $total_rows = $result->fetch_array()[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
    // Get the pages associated with this category:
    $query = 'SELECT id, title, description FROM pages WHERE category_id = ' . $_GET['id'] . ' ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 5';
 $result = $dbc->query($query);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // Pages available!

        // Fetch each record:
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            // Display each record:
            echo "<div><h4><a href=\"page.php?id={$row['id']}\">{$row['title']}</a></h4><p>{$row['description']}</p></div>\n";

        } // End of WHILE loop.
} else { // No pages available.
        echo '<p>There are currently no pages of content associated with this category. Please check back again!</p>';
    }

} else { // No valid ID.
    $page_title = 'Error!';
    include ('./includes/header.html');
    echo '<p class="error">Sorry, this page does not exist.</p>';
} // End of primary IF.


?>

<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="page.php?id=1">First</a></li>
    <li class="<?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="page.php<?php if($page_no <= 1){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?id=".($page_no - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
    </li>
    <li class="<?php if($page_no >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
        <a href="page.php<?php if($page_no >= $total_pages){ echo '#'; } else { echo "?id=".($page_no + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page.php?id=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT category FROM categories WHERE id = ' . $_GET['id'];

$page_no = $_GET['id'];

$query = 'SELECT id, title, description FROM pages WHERE category_id = ' . $_GET['id'] . ' ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 5';
```

Do you intend to use $_GET['id'] for both the page number and category_id? Shouldn't this be 2 separate variables? 
Like: $_GET['id'] for the category id, and $_GET['page'] for the page number

Comment: Yes, they coincidentally appear to be have the same name, but they are different. Both category and page tables have 'id'. Totally different